# Persist Collection JPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, persistence

I have a bean

```
public class Verbali implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;    
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_UTENTE", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Utenti idUtente;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idVerbale")
private Collection<PresenzeVerbali> presenzeVerbaliCollection;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "idVerbale")
private Collection<OrdineDelGiorno> ordineDelGiornoCollection;
```

when I put on my db record is created on the table Verbali but not records on the @OneToMany.
where wrong???

Comment: what table "Minutes" ? what table "Charts" ? what persistence code?

Comment: when I put on my db record is created on the table Verbali but not records on the @OneToMany. where wrong???

Comment: cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST ?

Answer (score 0):

When I have this type of rellations first I save the main class (in this case Verbali) and then save the childrens adding this new record to it.

```
Verbali verbali = new Verbali();

verbali.setIdUtente(retrieveUtente());
verbali = verbaliPersistence.save(verbali);

for(somestuff){
   PresenzeVerbali pv = new PresenzeVerbali();
   pv.setVerbali = verbali;
   presenzeVerballiPersistence.save(pv);
   //same with other collections
}
```